# ggplot draw a black box without separation between bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following chart

```
year <- 2022:2026
data <- 15:11
data2 <- 10:6
data3 <- 1:5

dat <- tibble(year, data, data2, data3)
data <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% pivot_longer(all_of(starts_with('data'))) %>% ungroup() %>%  
  mutate(first_categ = case_when('data2'==name | 'data3'==name ~ value,
                           TRUE ~ 0L))
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, fill = name))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = value), stat = 'identity', position = 'stack')+
  geom_col(aes(y=first_categ), alpha = 0, color = 'black', size = 2)
```

[image]

I'd like to have a separation between the two first colors (`data2` and `data3`) and the rest because for me, these colors belong to the same category.

Is it possible to remove the intermediate horizontal separation between the blue and green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trickier than you'd imagine. Effectively you need to map to different aesthetics and fake the guides to get this effect:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value, color = "data"), fill = "#F8766D", 
           position = 'stack') +
  geom_col(aes(y = value, fill = name), position = "stack", 
           data = subset(data, name != "data")) +
  stat_summary(fun = sum, aes(y = first_categ), color = 'black', 
           alpha = 0, size = 2, geom = "bar") +
  labs(color = "name") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = scales::hue_pal()(3)[-1], name = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "black", size = 1.5),
                             byrow = TRUE),
         color = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(20, 0, 20, 0),
        legend.key.size = unit(10, "mm"),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(-1.5, "mm"),
        legend.box.background = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 20, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: hey Allan, on this chart there is still the separation between the two.

Comment: @gaut there's a tiny bit of residual spacing, which you can get rid of with negative legend spacing in `theme` - see my update.

Comment: Sorry Allan, my question may not have been clear. id like to remove the horizontal black line separating the blue and green on the chart, not the legend. Basically draw a black box around both green and blue as if they were one, without separation. The legend part is interesting too so please keep it in there

Comment: Oh, sorry @gaut, I misunderstood. See my update.